# How can I display multiple modals on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, frontend

I want to display multiple videos on one pasge and I succeded in showing a video in modal, but I can't seem to figure out how to display more videos.
I am using a video tag and the tag is in a modal class. In js I have an openmodal function which loads the video and a closemodal function which pauses it.
How can I display as many videos as I want in one page? Thanks

Comment: have look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256885/multiple-jquery-dialogs-on-one-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256885/multiple-jquery-dialogs-on-one-page)

Comment: You need to provide the relevant code for what you've tried so far in the question and also tell us what's not working